# Strict positivity of the infimum of a set of sup-metrics

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

I am struggling with a subset of $\,l_\infty$ that has the following structure:

Let $a>0$ and consider set of sequences $S=\{x_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ such that $x_{k,k}=a$ and $x_{k,i}=0$ for all $i\neq k$. (Here, $x_{k,i} $ is to denote the $i$-th element of sequence $k$)

Consider an arbitrary bounded sequence $y\in l_\infty$ that is not in $S$.

Since $y\neq x_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, it is clear that the sup-metric $\,\sup_j|y_j-x_{k,j}|$ is strictly greater than zero. This, holds for all $k\in\,\mathbb{N}.$

I was wondering whether this is sufficient in order to be able to say that the infimum of  $\sup_j|y_j-x_{k,j}|$ over $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is also strictly greater than zero for all bounded sequences $y$ that are not in $S$.

Intuitively, I could consider a sequence $y$ that has zeroes everywhere apart from its, say, 10th element which I choose to be $a+\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon<a$ and arbitrarily small. Clearly,  $\sup_j|y_j-x_{10,j}|=\varepsilon$ while $\sup_j|y_j-x_{k,j}|=a$ for all $k\neq 10.$

So, I kind of feel that this shows that $$\inf\,\{\,\sup_j|y_j-x_{k,j}|\,:\, k\in\mathbb{N}\,\}\,=\,\varepsilon\,>\,0$$

However, since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrarily close to zero, I am worried that the fact that the infimum is the greatest lower boundary implies that the infimum is 0. On the other hand, it seems that for any $y\not\in S$ every element in  $\{\,\sup_j|y_j-x_{k,j}|\,:\, k\in\mathbb{N}\,\}$ must be strictly positive and the infimum of these elements is just the minimum which is thus strictly positive.

As you might have gleaned from my struggle, I am not extremely comfortable with the concept of an infimum.

Provided my intuition above is right, I would very much appreciate any pointers on how would I go about proving that $$\inf\,\{\,\sup_j|y_j-x_{k,j}|\,:\, k\in\mathbb{N}\,\}\,>\,0$$
for any bounded  $y\not\in S$

Thank you very much.

Comment: The definiton of $S$ is not clear. If you are fixing $a$ then $S$ has only one element so everything else is quite obvious.

Comment: Sorry about that. What I meant is that $a$ is a fixed, strictly positive real number and $S$ is the set of sequences of the form $x_1=(a,0,0,...)$, $x_2=(0,a,0,...)$, $x_3=(0,0,a,0,...)$ and so on. So for a fixed $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $S$ has countably infinite many sequences $x_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle inequality is what you need. Note that if $k \ne l$, then $\|x_k - x_l\| = |a|$. Therefore if $\|y - x_k\| < \frac {|a|}2$, then $\|y - x_l\| > \frac {|a|}2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am afraid that I'm not quite certain that I see why this implies that $inf_k||y-x_k||>0$. Is the following line of reasoning correct? If it exists, I pick one $x_k$ such that $||y-x_k||=\epsilon<|a|/2$ which implies that for all $l\neq k$ $||y-x_l||>|a|/2$. So $\{||y-x_k||:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a sequence such that one element is equal to $\epsilon$ while all other element are strictly greater than $\epsilon.$ So the infimum is $\epsilon>0$. If such a $x_k$ does not exist all elements are greater that $|a|/2$, anyway. Is that correct?

Comment: That is close to the proper reasoning. There is no guarantee that $\|y - x_k\| < |a|/2$ for any $k$, so your start by picking such a $k$ may not be possible. However, if such a $k$ does exist, then necessarily for all $l \ne k, \|y - x_l\| \ge |a|/2 > \|y - x_k\|$. Hence $\inf_l \|y - x_l \| = \|y - x_k\| > 0$. If such a $k$ does not exist, then $\inf_l\|y - x_l \| \ge |a|/2 > 0$.

Comment: Many thanks. Makes perfect sense.